# Read HDF5 Attribute as a block

Tags: c++, hdf5

HDF5 Version: HDF5-1.8.16

Language: C/C++

I am developing an application which has per HDF5 file: **~10K groups**, **~100 data sets** per group. Each dataset contains around 5 attributes.

I am currently using the 'group.openAttribute(attrName)' function to access the attributes. This call is extremely expensive, and is slowing down my reading process, specially because it calls some search functions into the library.

Question: is there an efficient way to read attributes: Kind of a bulk read.

Can someone point me to some example code I can use - (that is not the ones provided by the HDF5 group...)

Comment: I don't know of a bulked attribute read. One possible solution that comes to mind would be the creation of a compund datatype, so you would only need to read one attribute per dataset. Another solution might be the use of the parallel HDF5 C API, but I'm not sure of that. I'm curious to see if there is a better solution.